# How can ideologies be 'materialist'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

> ...,  there is no simple causal relationship of dependency or determination, either way, between morality and law. We would rather approach both morality and law as **ideological**, in that they are manifestations of, and seek to explain and justify, particular social and economic relationships. This essentially **materialist** approach to a degree explains the tensions between the competing ideologies of law and morality and explains why they sometimes conflict and why they change, albeit asynchronously, as underlying social relations change.

Source: p 2, The English Legal System 2012-2013, Gary Slapper

"Morality and law as *ideological*",  aren't 'material possessions and physical comfort', as required by [definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/materialism?q=materialist#materialism__8). So which definition is consistent with the context here? Sadly, I know little about philosophy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about learning English so much as a specialized question in the field of philosophy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it *is* the philosophical direction in which you want to look for an answer.

For good descriptions of philosophy, dictionary entries are usually simply too short. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialism) gives a bit more detailed description of the philosophical idea.

Usually, and also in this context, people will not invoke *materialism* in order to reminisce about Ludwig Feuerbach or the influence of hies works on Karl Marx. The important central idea of materialism is that the world consists of matter only, and that soul or spirit are not part of the world. That means materialism more or less positions itself squarely on the opposite side of, for instance, religion.

It is that non-religious, non-idealistic aspect that is usually referred to when materialism is mentioned. In the case of morality and law, a materialistic approach means that you do not establish them based on a holy book or divine order.

As the text says, it is "particular social and economical relationships" that lay at the basis of morality and law. Especially the economic relationships, that is, relationships based on *physical, material* property, that would mark such thinking as materialist.

A very simplified example would be that according to the Ten Commandments one has to *honour their parents*. In a materialistic moral and law system, such a rule is unlikely to exist, but one is not allowed to damage the economical position of ones parents beyond the normal expectations of the costs of a child. Parents are essentially not different from other agents on society except for some obligations, usually described as economical obligations from the parent to the child: parents have to take care of their children, protect them, are not allowed to abandon them or sell them and they are financially responsible for their offspring until a given age.

Not only does it seem an inverse responsibility, but the *nature* of the responsibility is a material one (provide food, provide shelter, provide money, provide school) rather than a  a non-material, maybe *spiritual* obligation (honour your parents).